# Generate c# .cs files from classes

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project where I need to construct instances of .cs files dynamically.

I use interfaces to structure the data, something like this (they do vary)

```
public interface IMetaClass
{
    string ParentName { get; set; }
    string Namespace { get; set; }
    string ClassName { get; set; }
    string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I also have classes that inherit from these interfaces

```
public class XavierMetaClass : IMetaClass
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

**Example** of construct and fill

```
var cell = new XavierMetaClass
{
    ParentName = mc.Parent.Name,
    Namespace = mc.Namespace,
    ClassName = mc.Name,
    FriendlyName = mc.FriendlyName,
    Description = mc.Description + "test"
};
```

[image]

**What I would like to do** is take this and construct a new .cs file with the data stored in the variable above with a result looking something like this.

```
public class CellPhone : IMetaClass
{
    public string ParentName { get { return "CatalogEntry"; } }
    public string Namespace { get { return "Mediachase.Commerce.Catalog.User"; } }
    public string ClassName { get { return "CellPhone"; } }
    public string FriendlyName { get { return "Cell sPhone"; } }
    public string Description { get { return "Contains meta data about phone test"; } }

    private readonly IMetaClass _metaClass;

    public CellPhone()
    {
        // Noop 
    }

    public CellPhone(IMetaClass metaClass)
    {
        _metaClass = metaClass;
    }
}
```

Are there any know frameworks of methods to help me achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Run-time serialization of your instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you have a few options.

1. CodeDom (good list of links and documentation from Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx))
2. T4 Templating
3. Custom Templating (this would be like building text files with little snippets and just piecing together the file with a tree of classes that emit those little pieces)

I have done all three and I would recommend T4 templating, and here is an exhaustive example on how to use it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/269362/Using-T4-Templates-to-generate-custom-strongly-typ

But you need to be willing to dig in and learn it because there is quite a bit to grasp.

Comment: Thanks, I did go with CodeDom since the assemblies I will create are quite simple. T4 seems a bit more easy to use if you are going for bigger stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Did you consider using [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) ?

Comment: Answers should be more comprehensive than just a link, otherwise it should just be a comment.  You should explain the link, put it in contents, summarize (in this case) the product and why it is appropriate here.  If you can't/won't do that, then it would be best to just post the link as a comment.